# Why did everyone turn away from this character?

Tags: character, ending, how-to-get-away-with-murder

This is a question about the very ending of the 6 season series *How to Get Away with Murder*, so obviously **HEAVY spoilers ahead**:

I am failing to understand the final reaction that the main cast had in the end towards one of them - it is clearly displayed that they are going to cut all the ties to one of them. This character is

Michaela, who is pushed away by Oliver, ignored by Connor and blocked on the phone by Laurel. I can understand why Annalise would cut the contact (Michaela has lied on the stand saying that Annalise was sleeping with decased Wes) or her not-so-ex boyfriend Gabriel (because he knows that Michaela participated in the murder of his father), but why Oliver, Connor and Laurel are so annoyed at her?

I understand, that before the trial

Laura, Michaela and Connor have made a deal with FBI to testify against Annalise, blaming her for mastermind the death of her husband (which was not true, although Annalise has helped to hide the evidence). Initially Michaela and Connor got a deal for 5 years in prison, but when they find out that Laura can go free, they try to renegotiate a better deal. The price for that is (I'm assuming) saying that Annalise and Wes, the (real killer, although acting in self defense) were lovers.

Michaela takes the deal and lies about Annalise and Wes on the stand, Connor refuses to lie and Laura has change of heart and testifies in Annalise's defense.

When the trial is concluded

Annalise is found not guilty, but Connor (according to the deal he has made and his own wishes) goes to prison. When Michaela tries to hug crying Oliver (Connor's husband), this most gently person from the whole cast pushes her away saying "It should be you!". Seconds later we can see that Laura won't take the Michaela's call.

Many years later, we can see that Laura, Connor and Oliver attend Annalise's funeral, they wave and smile at each other. In contrast, Michaela is absent.

I am struggling to understand the characters behavior here: They were all acting selfishly lying (or not) under oath, they were all negotiating deals to sell a friend. So why this one person is treated so much harsher by others?

Comment: Sorry, but we need the question to make sense. Please don't hide the majority of it under empty boxes. You already warned people of spoilers, hiding them after warning just makes no sense. For more information, see the corresponding [meta discussion](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/82/49) and others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is mostly about how they acted in the end and the way Michaela feels about it.

Firstly, yes they were all acting selfishly and they were all ready to lie but in the end not all of them did. Before it was too late, Laurel and Connor chose the right/truthful way because they couldn't bare to do such a thing to Annlise (and Wes).

Secondly, Michaela wasn't even remotely sorry as much as them for the things she was required to do. She somehow saw that it was her right to get out this all and have a good life (even if this means runining Annalise's). (Unlike Connor who volunteraly went to jail because he felt he deserved it)

Thus they were angry at her.

Answer (score 2):

A simple explanation to this would be her selfishness at the end.
Throughout the series it was shown to us that she gives into her desires, easily. She finds it convincing to grab any opportunity of happiness that comes her way and later regret. She is shown to be a power-seeker, *idolizing Annalise, Tegan and in her Middleton application her desire to become member at white house*.
So when she gets the opportunity to choose a better deal *(no jail-time)* as opposed to Connor's, she takes it and lies to Connor until the end.

That was the reason for Connor's side-eye reaction I believe. He has been feeling guilty since Sam's murder but Mechaela felt no guilt.

Oliver was simply pissed as she lied to Connor and took better deal while his husband served 5 years. He felt betrayed on Connor's behalf.

Laurel, just wanted to leave everything behind So she scraped her number in the end of the trial when Annalise won. She said that to Christopher right before she gets-in the car.

In the end it was shown that all three attends Annalise's funeral, but Macheala was taking oath at white house(pressumably).  Which  tells us that she didn't change and  her selfishness took her to places  she wanted.